# VS Code keybindings on Mac for cmd+delete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to set the command `` to be executed based upon the key binding `cmd+delete` which is not working (not working === nothing happens)

The default mapping is:

```
{ "key": "shift+cmd+k",       "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

My attempted setup is:

```
{ "key": "cmd+delete",        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Comment: What about `cmd+backspace`?

Comment: @Spork that works, please make this an answer and it will be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac Keyboards do not usually have a `delete` key, you may be thinking of `backspace`.

```
{ "key": "cmd+backspace",        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Answer (score 2):

In MAC keyboard if you press `delete` key it will work as `backspace`.

If you want to perform delete operation, then you have to hold `fn` key and press `delete` key.

So here your setup is correct but you have to press `cmd`+`fn`+`delete` keys.